# Pagination within category's posts

Tags: wordpress, loops, pagination, categories

I've 4 categories and each of it has between 10 and 40 posts. I activated the prev-next pagination on posts, but when I arrive at the last/first post of category X, the pagination doesn't loop within the category, but it shows the first/last of the prev/next category.

How can I make the pagination looping inside the category the current post is?

This is how my code looks like - but still, it won't go within the category.

```html
<?php next_post_link('<div class="single-nav-left col span_12 clr-margin">%link</div>', '&larr; %title', TRUE); ?>
<?php previous_post_link('<div class="single-nav-right col span_12">%link</div>', '%title &rarr;', TRUE); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the theme to alter the query in the `category.php` file. You can see how the custom query works in the WordPress codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

This could be a hint from where you can pick up:

`$query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=staff' );`